# How to resolve TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry :com/vividsolutions/jts/algorithm/Angle.class?

Tags: android, graphhopper

Everything was working fine , I added a button in my MainActivity and I had this error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/vividsolutions/jts/algorithm/Angle.class

I found two entries in my workspace.xml file . 
Here is my build.graddle :`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pfe.amina.usthbmap"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'app', 'assets'] } }
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper-core', version: '0.9-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
}

compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.7.0:natives-armeabi'
compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.7.0:natives-armeabi-v7a'
compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.7.0:natives-x86'



compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm:0.7.0'
compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.7.0'
compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-jts:0.7.0'
compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-themes:0.7.0'
compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
compile 'com.vividsolutions:jts-core:1.14.0'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: I added this to my  build.gradle :

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.vividsolutions', module: 'jts-core'
}
It worked for me

Comment: You should use a stable release like 0.8.2 instead of a snapshot